# Hardcode startup switches into INNO Setup script and retrieve them in [code] in InnoIDE

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I compile and then run my Inno script, I want to parse hard coded command line switches. So, instead of running my script as `c:\myInstall.exe /myswitch` I want to run it via IDE and have this switch included at the start here

[image]

With this code, I want to retrieve this switch in `ParamStr(x)`

```pascal
function MyParams(param: String): string;
begin
  
  MsgBox(ParamStr(3), mbError, MB_OK);
  Result := MyParameter;
end;
  {Parameter Detection--end}

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MyParams('XXX');
end;
```

Comment: You can't do what you're asking. `ParamStr` is provided by the OS from parameters passed on the command line of the program. You can add them for testing using the *Debug->Parameters* dialog.

Comment: @KenWhite I found another Inno Tool and there you can do this. In fact, it is better for debug of Inno than InnoIDE. I know, this is not a direct answer for Inno IDE but useful nevertheless. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool, which does this for you - you can set DEBUG variables if you use
***Inno Script Studio***

[image]